# metapost vardef returning multiple values

Tags: metapost

I need to write a metapost vardef returning several numerical values. Metapost seems to allow returning only one value.

How to make a metapost vardef returning multiple numerical values?

Comment: Hello Peteris, and welcome to tex.SE! It might just be me, but I have no idea what you are asking! What do you mean by metapost and vardef?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Metapost is a TeX friend that produces Postscript graphics; `vardef` is a primitive of Metapost, for defining a special type of macro.

Comment: It would be better if you gave an example of what's your aim.

Comment: Could you return a `pair` or a `color`?  Then you could extract the numbers with `xpart`, `ypart`, `redpart`, etc

Comment: In metapost you can return pairs but it's just 2 numbers. I need more than 2.

Comment: I want to manipulate 3D vectors. vardef should return sequences containing vectors and numericals

Comment: a `color` gives you three -- `redpart`, `greenpart`, `bluepart` get the components...

Answer (score 2):

In MetaPost a `begingroup ...;... endgroup` construct can only return a single value and a `vardef` automatically consists of one of these, but you can break out of it.
If the values are independent and you always return the same amount, you could use

```
vardef returnMultipleValues(expr x) =
    x + 1
  endgroup, begingroup
    x + 2
  endgroup, begingroup
    x + 3
  endgroup, begingroup
    x + 4
enddef;

for i := returnMultipleValues(3):
    show(i);
endfor;
```

Another approach which allows you to generate the values in the same group is based on Sergey Slyusarev's answer. The advantage here is that you do not have to remember to use `scantokens` with the result because that is already handled in the `vardef`:

```
 vardef returnMultipleValues (expr x) =
    save y, s;
    string s;
    numeric y[];
    y1 := x + 1;
    y2 := x + 2;
    y3 := x + 3;
    y4 := x + 4;
    s := decimal(y1) & "," & decimal(y2) & "," & decimal(y3) & "," & decimal(y4);
    expandafter
  endgroup
  expandafter gobbled expandafter true scantokens(s) gobble begingroup
enddef;

for i := returnMultipleValues(3):
    show(i);
endfor;
```

**EDIT**: I found a way to automate the first version and solving the grouping problem: Just use

```
def multireturn(expr first)(text values) =
  first for v = values: endgroup, begingroup v endfor
enddef;

vardef returnMultipleValues (expr x) =
  save y, s;
  numeric y[];
  y1 := x + 1;
  y2 := x + 2;
  y3 := x + 3;
  y4 := x + 4;
  multireturn(y1,y2,y3,y4)
enddef;

for i := returnMultipleValues(3):
    show(i);
endfor;
```

This works because `for` expands the list at the beginning, afterwards `v` is a capsule so it no longer is affected by groups.

Comment: Cool! The only thing (not directly related to the original question though) is that (expr first) in multireturn seems to rule out its use for suffixes (which can be quite handy), but it's possible to make multireturn accept single text argument, like this: def multireturn(text values) = save tmp; tmp := 0; for v = values: if (tmp > 0): endgroup, begingroup fi save i; tmp := 1; v endfor enddef;

Comment: @SergeySlyusarev I am not quite sure how you want to return a suffix in a verdef, but wouldn't that require replacing `for` with `forsuffixes` anyway? In any case, I think `save i` should be `save tmp`.

Comment: You're right, that would require an extra argument: `def multireturn(expr isSuffixes)(text values) = save isFirst; boolean isFirst; isFirst := true; if (isSuffixes): forsuffixes v = values: if (not isFirst): endgroup, begingroup fi save isFirst; boolean isFirst; isFirst := false; v endfor else: for v = values: if (not isFirst): endgroup, begingroup fi save isFirst; boolean isFirst; isFirst := false; v endfor fi enddef;` and maybe isn't worth it.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this, is to convert numerical values to strings, concatenate them and return as a single string. Then you can get the values back using `scantokens`

```
vardef returnMultipleValues (expr x) =
    save y;
    numeric y[];
    y1 := x + 1;
    y2 := x + 2;
    y3 := x + 3;
    y4 := x + 4;
    decimal(y1) & "," & decimal(y2) & "," & decimal(y3) & "," & decimal(y4)
enddef;

string something;

something = returnMultipleValues(3);

for i := scantokens(something):
    show(i);
endfor;
```

Similarly you can use paths for the same thing:

```
vardef returnMultipleValues (expr x) =
    save y;
    numeric y[];
    y1 := x + 1;
    y2 := x + 2;
    y3 := x + 3;
    y4 := x + 4;
    (x, y1) -- (x, y2) -- (x, y3) -- (x, y4)
enddef;

path something;

something = returnMultipleValues(3);

for i := 0 step 1 until length(something):
    show(ypart(point i of something));
endfor;
```

Or, if the number of values you want to return is limited to 2 or 3, as @thruston suggested, you could use a `pair` or a `color`.

Comment: Thanks Sergey This may be a way to go. But now I am just trying to write a program using vardefs which return numericals or pairs.

Comment: Paths are quite natural way to store pairs. And you can incorporate pairs into strings as well, and even mix different types like this "(" & decimal(y1) & "," & decimal(y2) & ") , " & decimal(y3) & "," & decimal(y4). But i agree with @egreg more details on what exactly you want to achieve would help a lot.