# METAPOST vardef returning multiple and non-numeric types as a single answer?

Tags: metapost

I would like a `vardef` macro to return the pair of a picture and a bounding box. I don't want to use the `setbound` operator, because as soon as I do that, I cannot access the components of the picture anymore with `pathpart`.

I found [metapost vardef returning multiple values](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448740/metapost-vardef-returning-multiple-values) but that is about returning multiple values of the same numeric type. Is it possible to have `vardef` return a set of (picture, path) or (picture, picture) in some way? If not, I need to make two `vardef` macros for each result type.

I tried many things, amongst which:

```
vardef Foo( expr w, h)
% define pic
pic
end group,begingroup
% define pic
pic
endif

picture foo[]; foo = Foo( 2, 4);
```

Comment: Cross post: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2020/097257.html

Answer (score 2):

If you don't completely ignore all the syntax rules of MetaPost, as you did in your original post, then this works without a problem.

```
vardef Foo(expr w, h) =
    image (
        draw fullcircle xyscaled(w, h) ;
    )
endgroup, begingroup
    image (
        draw fullsquare xyscaled(w, h) ;
    )
enddef;

beginfig(0) ;
for p := Foo(2cm, 4cm):
    draw p ;
endfor ;
endfig ;

end ;
```

I'm using the MetaFun format here, so `mpost` has to be told to load it:

```
$ mpost -mem=metafun test.mp
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't filly answer my question, as I need to do something like `mypic := <firstvalue>; mypth := <secondvalue>`, so the for loop will be hard for me to do.

Comment: @gctwnl If you had asked a more useful question, you would have received a more useful answer, but I saw that you already got answers on the ConTeXt list.